# Flutter Form Builder - FormBuilderDropdown does not display correct value on screen

Tags: flutter

I am creating a form with the plugin `flutter_form_builder` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder).

When I use `FormBuilderDropdown`, you can selected a different value, but it won't show you the selected value on screen. Normally you have a `value` property, but this widget does not have that. It only has an `initial value`.

#### Note

When I removed the whole `onChanged` method, it does show me the right value on the screen. BUT I need this onChanged method so I cannot remove it...

#### Code from

```dart
final shippingPackagesList = [
        {"key": "dhlpwc-parcelshop", "label": "DHL ServicePoint"},
        {"key": "dhlpwc-home", "label": "Thuis bezorgen"},
        {
          "key": "local_pickup:7",
          "label": "Afhalen in de winkel in Heerlen, Limburg"
        },
      ];

return Column(
children: [
FormBuilder(
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              FormBuilderDropdown(
                                  items: shippingPackagesList
                                      .map((shippingPackage) =>
                                          DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: shippingPackage['key'],
                                            child: Text(shippingPackage['label']!),
                                          ))
                                      .toList(),
                                  name: 'shipping_key',
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    String shippingPackageKey =
                                        value.toString();

                                    // Set selected shipping method in cart view model

                                    cartViewModel
                                        .setSelectedShippingPackageByString(
                                            shippingPackageKey);
                                    cartViewModel.updateTotalCosts();
                                  },
                                  // initialValue: "dhlpwc-parcelshop",
                                  hint: Text("Kies verzendmethode"),
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero)),
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            ],
                          )),
Text(
                          '€ ${cartViewModel.selectedShippingPackage!.totalCost.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
]
)
```

How can I solve this problem? Or is this a bug?

#### EDIT

#### Cart view model functions

```dart
class CartViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {

// Properties
ShippingPackage? _selectedShippingPackage;
double? _totalWithShippingPrice;
// Getters
ShippingPackage? get selectedShippingPackage => _selectedShippingPackage;
double? get totalWithShippingPrice => _totalWithShippingPrice;

void setSelectedShippingPackageByString(String shippingPackageKey) {
    for (var shippingPackage in cart!.shippingPackages) {
      if (shippingPackage.key == shippingPackageKey) {
        _selectedShippingPackage = shippingPackage;
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

void updateTotalCosts() {
    double total =
        cart!.totals.articlesWithTax + selectedShippingPackage!.totalCost;
    _totalWithShippingPrice = total;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

#### Main

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CartViewModel()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'App',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyMainHome(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### Pubspec yaml

add  `provider: ^6.0.2` in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with the `flutter_form_builder` and the `FormBuilderDropdown` specifically. Writing this code based on the example of the package:

```
class Home72124205 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home72124205({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home72124205> createState() => _Home72124205State();
}

class _Home72124205State extends State<Home72124205> {
  List<String> locationsList = [
    'New York',
    'Tokyo',
    'London',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FormBuilderDropdown(
          name: 'location',
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Location',
          ),
          initialValue: locationsList.first,
          allowClear: true,
          onChanged: (value){
            print(value);
          },
          items: locationsList
              .map((location) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: location,
                child: Text(location),
              )).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was not able to reproduce your issue. The widget works as intended. The label on the `dropdown` changes, the `onChange` gets called and the code gets executed.

As we don't have access to your full application, I am unable debug your issue.

Are you able to experiment with this example and test if, within the context of your application, the problem still happens?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. I found the problem but did not find a solution. It works when I delete these 2 lines: `cartViewModel.setSelectedShippingPackageByString(shippingPackageKey);` and `cartViewModel.updateTotalCosts();`. However, I do need them to update the `shipping cost` and `total costs`. And display it on the screen.  I added the code of these 2 methods so you could take a look at them and maybe see what is wrong.

Comment: After reading the code you added for clarification, it seems you are using `Provider` for State Management. There could be an issue with the redrawing that the `FormBuilderDropdown` does automatically when the user makes the change, and then clashes with the 2 `notifyListeners()` calls you are making in a row. Are you not getting any errors that you can share?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I removed the `notifyListeners()` in both of the methods and now the correct value is displayed in the `dropdownbox`. I am not getting any errors in the terminal. I also removed one `notifyListeners()` but that is not making any difference.

Comment: What about calling `notifyListeners()` only at the end of the `onChanged`? Does the issue persist?

Comment: Hey I tried to to that. But the issue is still the same

Comment: I found something interesting... I added a timer. So in the `onChanged` method, I call the `notifyListeners()` after 2 seconds. And the following happens: The value of the `combobox` changes, and after 2 seconds the value of the combobox is gone. But then the costs are updated on the screen. It seems like it's overriding or something..

Comment: There must be something else going on in your code that we can't reproduce here.

Comment: Hmm I can make the code reproducible if you'd like, but it will take some time

Comment: That's up to you. We are just trying to help.

Comment: Oke, will do that, because the bug is really weird to me. Give me a few minutes to add the remaining code

Comment: Oke, I added the remaing code you should be able to reproduce the error